# I cannot open a new VSCode instance from the integrated VSCode terminal while being a non-root superuser on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, remote-server, ubuntu-20.04, vscode-remote

I use a VSCode to connect to a remote server using ssh.

Currently, only the files in the root folder are displayed by VSCode.
I have a superuser dacomis that contains a folder named cardano-v.
I would like to be able to create a new instance of VSCode using `code .` or `code -n cardano-v`. The new instance should display the content of the folder like in the first picture where I was the root user.

When I follow the same steps as above while being the superuser dacomis for the folder cardano-v, nothing happens. (2nd picture)
I installed VSCode on the user using snap.

What can I do?
Thank you!

[image: 1st picture]
[image: 2nd picture]

Comment: You question is very confusing. You've got three pictures condensed into one picture. It's unclear what you're trying to show. Is the second instance in the photo what you want or what you don't want? What's the difference between the the top left screenshot and the bottom screenshot. Please clarify the behavior that happens and the behavior that you want.

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking now. Have you tried first using VScode to directly ssh as the user dacomis? It seems like just installing vscode on that user using snap isn't enough; you need VScode to install some vscode remote server on that user, which happens when you first ssh into a user. So first ssh into dacomis, then go back to root ssh and see if you can open a folder using dacomis user. If that works, let me know and I can add as an answer.

Comment: I tried doing this but to no success. I had to remove the root connection from the .ssh/config file in my local machine. When I had only the dacomis superuser connection I could connect to the VSCode using the Remote Explorer and using `ssh dacomis@-serverIP-` now I am succesful. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I resolved my problem.
In the .ssh/config file on my Windows machine that I use to connect to the remote server, I have there were 2 instances that were trying to connect to the same server:

```
Host -serverIP-
  HostName -serverIP-
  User root

Host -serverIP-
  HostName -serverIP-
  User dacomis
```

I deleted the content of this file, I established a new connection with the remote server from VSCode using the Remote Server extension and the command `ssh dacomis@-serverIP-`. Where dacomis is the superuser that I would like to connect to.

Now the .ssh/config file contains only this user:

```
Host -serverIP-
  HostName -serverIP-
  User root
```

Now I am able to connect to the remote server and create a new VSCode instance with a folder using the famous command `code testFolder` and my integrated bash terminal is by default opened on the dacomis superuser and not root.

Answer (score 1):

As @wxz pointed out, remote-VS-code and the "normal" VS-code are not the same.

---

*TL;DR: After installing code via snap, the command `code` is no longer suitable to open a remote instance but rather tries to open the GUI-software on your remote machine.*

---

When SSH-ing into a remote system, The local system's vs-code installs a so called **visual studio code server** on your remote system. That generates the information that is supposed to be displayed and handles the terminal-IO etc. The local vs-code instance then receives all this information from the remote (ubuntu) server and renders it into a normal-looking VS-code instance.

Installing code on the remote system (e.g. from snap) installs the full vs-code environment on your remote system. After installing VS-code on the remote system, you could plug Mouse, Monitor and Keyboard into your Ubuntu-System and use VS-code as a GUI-program. This is not what you want. Sadly, installing the full VS-code overwrites the `code`-command to point to the new software.

#### Possible steps to (hopefully) solve your problem:

1. Uninstall the snap VS-code completely (on the remote ubuntu machine)
2. Open an empty vs-code instance on your local machine
3. Open the terminal in the local VS-code instance, enter `code <path to open it in>`.

   - This should install the vs-code-server version according to your local instances version
   - Now try again to open a new vs code instance from an existing one

#### Edit: If you do not want to uninstall snap VS-code

You could try to install the vs-code-server on your remote and start it not with the `code`-command (as that is hoggged by the GUI-VS-code).

Comment: Thank you, kind stranger!
I already resolved the issue using the solution I explained in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.